# S3 - Kubernetes probe

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I have the following situation:

Application uses S3 to store data in Amazon. Application is deployed as a pod in kubernetes. Sometimes some of developers messes with access data for S3 (eg. user/password) and application fails to connect to S3 - but pod starts normally and kills previous pod version that worked OK (since all readiness and aliveness probes are OK). I thought of adding S3 probe to readiness - in order to execute `HeadBucketRequest` on S3 and if this one succeeds it is able to connect to S3. The problem here is that these requests cost money, and I really need them only on start of the pod.

Are there any best-practices related to this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you (quote) "... really need them [the probes] only on start of the pod" then look into adding a [startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-startup-probe).

In addition to what startup probes help with - pods that take longer time to start - a startup probe will make it possible to verify a condition only at pod startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Readiness and liveness prove as for checking the health of POD or container while running. You scenario is quite wired but with Readiness & liveness probe it wont work as it fire on internal and which cost money.

in this case you might can use the **lifecycle** hook :

```
containers:
      - image: MAGE_NAME
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:  ["/bin/sh", "-c", "script.sh"]
```

which will run the hook at starting of the container you can keep shell file inside the POD or image.

inside shell file you can right logic if **200** response **move a head** and container get started.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/